# Postgis/SQL Select tuples such that the first tuple item is unique and the items geometries intersect

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

This question is particularly for Postgres 9.4

Lets say I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A(id INT);
CREATE TABLE B(id INT);
```

I'd like to have all tuples (A, B) with a certain condition such that
among selected tuples all have different A column:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (A.id) A.id, B.id WHERE condition(A,B);
```

However `DISTINCT ON` will perform sorting in memory after all the tuples have been selected and I will like to not select tuples with duplicate A.id at all.

How can this be done in an efficient way?

### EDIT:

both A and B have unique ids

### EDIT2:

Here is the complete setup:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
DROP TABLE A;
DROP TABLE B;
CREATE TABLE A(shape Geometry, id INT);
CREATE TABLE B(shape Geometry, id INT, kind INT);
CREATE INDEX ON A USING GIST (shape);`
```

I would like to do the following:

```
SELECT A.id, B.id FROM A, B
WHERE B.id = (SELECT B.id FROM B WHERE
     ST_Intersects(A.shape, B.shape)
     AND ST_Length(ST_Intersection(A.shape, B.shape)) / ST_Length(A.shape) >= 0.5 AND B.kind != 1 LIMIT 1)`
```

which works (I believe), however is not necessarily the most efficient way. The table `A` has orders of magnitude more rows than table B. So
I am not even sure if the GiST index is right.

I am also aware that the order of arguments in  ST_Intersects can have a significant effect on run time. What should the correct order be?

Answer (score 1):

If you want just one row for each "A", you can use a correlated subquery (or lateral join):

```
select a.id,
       (select b.id
        from b
        where condition(a, b)
        limit 1
       ) as b_id
from a;
```

This should stop testing for rows from `b` when the first one is found -- which I imagine is the best approach performance-wise.

If none are found, you will get a `NULL` value.  You can wrap this in a subquery and filter out `NULL`s.

Comment: how bad do you think DISTINCT ON a.id and a CROSS JOIN with the inner query is? I would run and test it myself but It takes forever

Comment: @iggy . . . Bad.  It generates all the combinations.  Runs the function on all the rows.  Then it takes just one value.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
WITH distinct_a as (
SELECT DISTINCT a.id 
FROM A)
SELECT A.id, B.id 
FROM distinct_a, B
WHERE condition(A,B)
```

The CTE (`WITH ...`) will select all distinct values first. Then selected values will be used in the next query.

Comment: the problem is that there are multiple B that satisfy condition(A, B), and not the fact that there are multiple A's with same id

Comment: In other words - you want to stop after the first match on `condition(A, B)` for every A ?

Comment: An effective way to do this depends on the `condition(A, B)` and index on A and B. Can you show them?